# Unable to download tzdbgen jar

Tags: github, timezone, java

I want to download this file tzdbgen-1.0.1.jar. But I get this message:

```
You do not have access to this repository.
Return to the previous page or go back to your dashboard.
```

when I try to download it from https://github.com/akashche/tzdbgen . How can I download the jar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reached out to the repo owner at github and now the jar is made available at :
https://github.com/akashche/tzdbgen/releases .